# Unable to create an db.r3.8xlarge SQL Server EE instance in ap-southeast-2

Tags: sql-server, licensing, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I am getting a cloud formation error when attempting to create an RDS instance in `ap-southeast-2` and would appreciate your help:

> RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: `DBInstanceClass=db.r3.8xlarge, Engine=sqlserver-ee, EngineVersion=13.00.2164.0.v1, LicenseModel=bring-your-own-license`. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html) it looks like it is a valid combination.  I can create other database instances with other `DBInstanceClass`es but not with `db.r3.8xlarge`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it might be helpfull,if error message shows,which parameter is not correct

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, nothing in the documentation suggests that this combination is unsupported (see documentation references below). I would suggest filing an [AWS Support Request](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=technical) regarding this issue for further internal investigation.

Another possibility is that you have a limited number of BYOL licenses- the number required per instance is determined by the instance size, and `r3.8xlarge` requires **32** licenses according to the [SQL License Mobility](https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/licensemobility/sql/) page.

---

Documentation references:

#### `DBInstanceClass`/`Engine`:

The [DB Instance Class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html) documentation section lists the allowed DB Instance Class types per database engine.

For [`db.r3`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html#Concepts.DBInstanceClass.R3), the Microsoft SQL Server engine lists the following:

> Enterprise Edition: Supported for BYOL. Supported for License Included on `db.r3.2xlarge` and larger.

#### `LicenseModel`:

According to [Bring Your Own License (BYOL)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Concepts.General.Licensing.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.Licensing.BYOL) documentation,

> The Bring Your Own License model is supported on Amazon RDS for the following Microsoft SQL Server database editions:
>
> - Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016)

#### `EngineVersion`:

The [Microsoft SQL Server on Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html) documentation states the following:

> Amazon RDS supports DB instances running several versions and editions of Microsoft SQL Server. You can use the following versions and editions:
>
> - SQL Server 2016
>
>   - Version `13.0.2164.0`, `CU2`, for all editions, and all regions except South America (São Paulo)

The [CreateDBInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html) `EngineVersion` API documentation confirms:

> #### Microsoft SQL Server 2016
>
> - `13.00.2164.0.v1` (supported for all editions, and all AWS regions except `sa-east-1`)

Comment: Thanks, I can create the larger instance - db.m4.10xlarge - which consumes more licenses so don't know what the issue with this one at the moment.  Will raise a support call with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the documentation the AWS CLI offers with the following command also an option to lookup valid combinations:

`aws describe-orderable-db-instance-options`

This command also offers some parameters. Look [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-orderable-db-instance-options.html) for parameters and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html) for examples on how to query data.

Applying this command (`aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --db-instance-class db.r3.8xlarge --engine sqlserver-ee --engine-version 13.00.2164.0.v1 --license-model bring-your-own-license`) on your use case leads to the following error:

`An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions operation: Invalid license model 'bring-your-own-license' for engine 'sqlserver-ee'. Valid license models are: license-included`